# Does using an enum make an application less portable?

Tags: java, enums

I know this question sounds bizarre, but that's what my manager told me. When I proposed a new design that made use of an `enum`, he said, ***"No, ..."***, and then went on to make an offhand comment that making use of such a construct actually makes the application ***"less portable"***.

Is this true? I suspect that it's not.

Comment: Portable meaning you cannot convert it into another programming language easily or portable meaning you cannot run it on another java version?

Comment: I have seen cases where the way `enum` is used made the application less extensible but I don't think it will make your application less portable.

Comment: @Matt Ball, I suspect he meant Java as a language: source code portability...he really didn't elaborate though. He did make a remark afterward that he's "unfamiliar with enums and has trouble understanding them", but it just confused me.

Comment: Your manager is right: it will be less likely to be portable back in time.

Comment: @little bunny - you're faced with a bigger issue than enums. That said, one approach that might help in this case would be familiarizing your manager with enums -- e.g., in a brown bag to your team covering "recent" language features. Highlight the additional costs/risks of representing enums in ways other than supported by the language (e.g., consider typechecking). If possible, mention specific bugs that could have been avoided entirely.

Comment: @Andy, I completely agree. I think I'm starting to gray. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask him for me details... it does mean you wouldn't be able to compile the code in Java 1.4 or earlier, but that's not a terribly good justification.

Sounds like your manager may be confused... but you should always press for details.

Comment: Tip: Before talking to your manager, attempt to compile your application under Java 1.4.  If it fails, then your application is already incompatible with Java 1.4 .

Answer (score 1):

Does the application interact with other programming languages, i.e., via an API?  That's the only sense in which I can imagine that an enum would cause problems.  Otherwise, it's just an integer/long underneath in most languages and provides an extra layer of compile-time safety checking that can only make your program more robust.

Comment: in fact, enums in Java are "singleton" objects (one for each value) that wrap just an integer value (or some other values, depending on your constructor) so that they even remain typesafe (and have correct toString) when cast into an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your manager wants to maintain portability with JDK 1.4 and below he is wrong. There is nothing unportable in enum as it's part of Java language. Can he elaborate his point?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues come to mind with enums.

First is version portability. 'enums' have been with java since version 5.0 (aka 1.5). So if he's interested in maintaining backward compatibility with older systems, this may be a good cause for concern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29).

The other issue that comes up, sometimes, is how to serialize/store enumerations. Enums are generally stored in memory as some index which gets translated by the compiler that have little to do with the actual string. This is great for program performance and is generally fine if you never need to save / store / share your enumerations. But it can cause a lot of trouble when you try to serialize / store it to databases for others to read.

Comment: Java enum have a `toString()` and `Enum.valueOf()` for the opposite direction, so printing should not be a problem. You can also wrap a custom value (like a char or String) in each enum value by defining a constructor, and then use this value for serialization.